# add to cart function creates wrong array

Tags: php, arrays, session, shopping-cart

I try to add product to the shopping cart but I have some problems with the loop logic.
This function should add new product and check if product id is already in the cart. If it is in the cart it should add 1 to existing product or the quantity selected by user.
Here is some code that I have:

```
function AddToCart($pid, $q)
{
$quantity = $q;
$product_id = $pid;
if (is_array($_SESSION['products']))
    {
    foreach($_SESSION['products'] as $key => $my_value)
        {
        if ($pid === $my_value['product_id'])
            {
            if ($quantity != 1)
                {
                $quantity = $my_value['quantity'] + $quantity;
                $_SESSION['products'][$key]['quantity'] = $quantity;
                }
              else
                {
                $quantity = $my_value['quantity'] + 1;
                $_SESSION['products'][$key]['quantity'] = $quantity;
                }
            }
          else
            {
            $_SESSION['products'][] = array(
                'product_id' => $product_id,
                'quantity' => $quantity,
            );
            }
        }
    }
  else
    {
    $_SESSION['products'][] = array(
        'product_id' => $product_id,
        'quantity' => $quantity,
    );
    }
}
```

the var_dump of the $_SESSION will be the following:

```
   array(8) { 
   [0]=> array(2) { ["product_id"]=> int(4) ["quantity"]=> int(1) } 
   [1]=> array(2) { ["product_id"]=> int(10) ["quantity"]=> int(1) } 
   [2]=> array(2) { ["product_id"]=> int(11) ["quantity"]=> int(2) } 
   [3]=> array(2) { ["product_id"]=> int(11) ["quantity"]=> int(3) } 
   [4]=> array(2) { ["product_id"]=> int(12) ["quantity"]=> int(2) } 
   [5]=> array(2) { ["product_id"]=> int(12) ["quantity"]=> int(3) } 
   [6]=> array(2) { ["product_id"]=> int(12) ["quantity"]=> int(4) } 
   [7]=> array(2) { ["product_id"]=> int(12) ["quantity"]=> int(5) } }
```

Although I add only 4 products: id 4, 10, 11 and 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function AddToCart($pid, $q){  
    if(!is_array($_SESSION['products'])){
        $_SESSION['products'] = array();
    }
    foreach($_SESSION['products'] as $key=>$my_value){
        if($pid === $my_value['product_id']){
            $_SESSION['products'][$key]['quantity'] += $q;
            return true;
        }   
    }
    $_SESSION['products'][] = array('product_id' => $pid,
                                    'quantity' => $q);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: should be working but after I add 3rd new product the condition if($pid === $my_value['product_id']){
            $_SESSION['products'][$key]['quantity'] += $q;
        } runs instead of else{
            $_SESSION['products'][] = array('product_id' => $pid,
                                            'quantity' => $q);
        } and I get the same result

Comment: oops sorry, the code was completely wrong. try the new version if you still need it.

Comment: Thank you very much!:) I've changed code a little bit so it works fine now:)